# Advice and experience for testing a CN1 app

Tags: codenameone

I would like to start automating the testing of my app written in CodenameOne, but I find it difficult to visualize how to use the [TestRecorder](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/performance-debugging.html#_device_testing_framework/unit_testing) (section "Unit Testing") for "industrial" testing.

If anyone here is already using it, could you share a few tips about how you use it?

E.g. how do you use the different "Asserts" buttons, how do you structure your tests into suites and how do you chain them together (e.g. so each test case will start in the right context like where in the navigation structure it is supposed to run), do you need to manually edit the tests, ... And is there anything to be aware of before creating lots of tests interactively, e.g. to avoid that your tests are invalidated by some irrelevant change to your UI?

I read in the [blog post](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/test-recorder-toolbar.html) from May 2017 that the TestRecorder "wasn’t picked up by many developers and as such it stagnated". I tried TestRecorder and immediately came across a seemingly basis error in it (missing test for null) when recording a test case using the Toolbar, which gave the impression it is still the case. So, if anyone here is using another approach that is working well for you, I'd love to hear about that.

Comment: I also have difficulties to find a way to automate tests of a Codename One app: in my opinion this question is very interesting.

Comment: Glad I’m not the only one - sometimes you ask only to realize you missed something obvious

Answer (score 0):

See the test classes we use to test Codename One itself here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/tree/master/tests/core

You can use the test recorder to generate a skeleton but you can do this manually just like any test. The test API lets you invoke the app or just pieces of it and perform assertions on the behaviors within.

Comment: Thanks Shai, it’s interesting to see how you guys test, but it doesn’t really answer my question about how other developers test real CN1 apps. I tried a couple of times to get started with Test Recorder but never really felt reassured that it was the best way considering the big investment a test suite is going to be.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding where you're stuck. The recorder is pretty simplistic. You need to take the recorded file and edit it with the proper clicks/assertions to reproduce the various test cases you define for your app. In our samples you can see various examples for assertions in the code which you can use similarly to assure that various conditions happen. E.g. you can verify that a specific button in a specific form has text X. The main challenge is in deciding the test cases.

Comment: Thanks Shai. I’m simply looking for experience from someone who has build real “industrial” size test suites for a CN1 app. The fact that Test Recorder crashes w basic null pointer issues as mentioned above gives the impression it’s not used, so maybe someone has other good ways to test.